# How to get API that will give me a UAN when provided with a mobile number?

Tags: aadhaar

Does anybody know how some companies are able to get the EPFO data as in mobile number to uan integration working? Can somebody point out where they are getting this data without any OTP authentication ?

I tried working through API setu as well as umang app, but I couldn't find any similar data source where I can sign up and get mobile number to UAN without any OTP authentication?

Comment: You may want to include definitions of these abbreviations as they are not obvious; EPFO, UAN. I searched for it and it seems to be specific to India.

Comment: Yep, they are India specific, EPFO is Employees' Provident Fund Organisation, UAN is the unique number assigned by that entity.